# NestJS - request timeout

Tags: express, nestjs

How to set timeout for all requests and if timedout then respond with custom json?

I tried to use:

```
import * as timeout from 'connect-timeout';

import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ApplicationModule } from './app.module';

const port = process.env.PORT || 3020;

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(ApplicationModule);
  app.use(timeout('5s'));
  app.use(haltOnTimedOut);

  await app.listen(port);
} 
bootstrap();


function haltOnTimedOut (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.timedout){
      next();
  } else {
      res
        .status(408)
        .json({ status: 'error', data: 'timeout'})
  }
}
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 24):

To increase the **nestjs - API application server request/response timeout**, I did the following in main.js

```
const server = await app.listen(5000);
server.setTimeout(1800000); // 600,000=> 10Min, 1200,000=>20Min, 1800,000=>30Min
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem! You can do something like this too: server.setTimeout(30 * 60 * 1000);

Comment: is it possible to set only for particular rout?

Answer (score 11):

NestJS has a feature called Interceptors. Interceptors can be used for the purpose of forcing timeouts, they demonstrate it here, [TimeoutInterceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#more-operators).

Suppose you have got your Interceptor in a file called `timeout.interceptor.ts`:

```
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler, RequestTimeoutException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError, TimeoutError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      timeout(5000),
      catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
          return throwError(new RequestTimeoutException());
        }
        return throwError(err);
      }),
    );
  };
};
```

After this, you have to register it, which can be done in several ways. The global registration way is shown below:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
app.useGlobalInterceptors(new TimeoutInterceptor());
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that a lot of code can run before interceptors (eg your guards or middleware), and you still want your timeout to apply to those.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a express instance to the `NextFactory.create(module, expressInstance)` so you can add the middleware to that express instance like

```
const expressInstance = express();
express.use(timeout('4'));
express.use((err, res, req, next) => req.jsonp(err)); // DON'T USE FOR PRODUCTION
const app = NestFactory.create(AppModule, express);
```

It should work.

Comment: Even with my solution timeout works but I'm unable to change default response from html to json I provied.

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/timeout/blob/master/index.js#L82 If you check this code this returning the error to the middleware which is handled by the the error handler. You can write function like this `(err, res, req, next) => { req.jsonp(err) }` so it can be resolved. NOTE: Dont use this in production use your own error handler

Answer (score -1):

Move your `app.use(timeout('5s'));` out of your `bootstrap` function and remove the `else` block from `haltOnTimedOut` function as well.

And try calling your `bootstrap` function as a middleware as given below,

```
app.use(boostrap, timeout('5s'), bodyParser.json(), haltOnTimedout, function (req, res, next) {
if (req.timedout) return
      res
        .status(408)
        .json({ status: 'error', data: 'timeout'})
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: How could app use bootstrap if app is defined inside bootstrap function?